# How to get src of img with lxml in python?

Tags: python, lxml

I try to parse src from image tag in python with lxml, but when I try to output imageurl I get following:

```
[<Element img at 0x921f68c>]
```

Here is my code:

```
xhtml = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
imageUrl = xhtml.xpath('//img[@alt="something"]')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just append `/@src` to your xpath expression:

```
imageUrl = xhtml.xpath('//img[@alt="something"]/@src')
```